# lotus notes: intercept ESC keyboard button press

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

in lotus notes script i use a DialogBox to display a form where users put data.

But if the user press ESC keyboard button all data that user put in my DialogBox will be lost.

Is there a method to intercept when user press "ESC" button and save all data of the DialogBox form ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use QueryClose event on Form.

I see 3 ways how solve your task:

1. Save data into User Profile (see more details here: [GetProfileDocument](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETPROFILEDOCUMENT_METHOD.html))
2. Save data into notes.ini (more details here: [SetEnvironmentString](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SETENVIRONMENTVAR_METHOD.html))
3. Add a validation on QueryClose that will ask User if it's OK to close Dialog dialog. Parameter **Continue** controls if Dialog can be closed or not.

See screen with QueryClose event below.

[image]

**NOTE**: if you want to have different behavior on if user clicked Cancel button and Esc than make Cancel as a custom button, so it first set some values to dialog and than fire closing, in such way on QueryClose event you will know how user fired close dialog event.